# Image with border in corners - space below img

Tags: html, css, image

I want to create image with the border in opposite corners (using `:: after` and `:: before`). I almost got it, BUT the image doesn't cover the whole space in the div. Below the image there is some empty space (marked red in jsfiddle), and I don't understand what is the reason. The most important thing is that the image's height change the width. Could you explain me what I did wrong? :)

This is my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/ndy79hvo/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the default `baseline` vertical alignment for images, which leaves some empty space below that baseline (where the descenders of letters like j, p, y would go). Add `display: block;` to the CSS rule for your image to change this.

https://jsfiddle.net/tpqzr3w2/

Comment: @dippas: among other reasons: because it's faster and it helps immediately

Comment: the duplicate exists for some reason, This looks like a rep farm.

Comment: what's a rep farm?

Comment: OMFG... I just delete this question for few minutes... @Johannes thank you you are very kind and helpfull.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126987/what-is-rep-farming

Comment: @dippas I hope you get moderator rule soon :D